# Error when backing up MYSQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm sorry for the stupid question, but when i run this code i always get a error.  This code is meant to get a backup from my mysql database and display it.  For your information, remote mysql is enabled.

Here is the code:

```
private void backupDatabaseButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u user -p pass db > C:\\backup.sql");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I replaced the user, pass and db with the correct login details, but i always get an error.

Here is the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at databaseTools.backupDatabaseButtonActionPerformed(databaseTools.java:23)
    at databaseTools.access$0(databaseTools.java:20)
    at databaseTools$1.actionPerformed(databaseTools.java:51)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Does anyone know why i get this error?  Thanks.

Comment: It seems it cannot find `mysqldump`? Is it in your PATH, and if not, what happens if you give the FULL path to `mysqldump`?

Comment: Does every computer have mysqldump?

Comment: Also note that `mysqldump -u user -p pass db > C:\\backup.sql` will not work. The space after `-u` is optional and if you want to specify a password you must not use a space after `-p`

Comment: Also, **never use the `String` version of `Runtime.exec`** - this causes issues with spaces. You should use the [`String[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) version and pass in the arguments individually.

Comment: @HrachGhapantsyan: if you have installed MySQL server, you also should have mysqldump. Without MySQL you do not have mysqldump. Most computers will not have mysqldump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried giving the full path to the mysqldump executable?

Comment: No, do you have any idea as to where i would find it?  Im using a remote server.

Comment: I cannot find the MYSQL dump, will i need to install mysql?

Comment: If it's not installed, yes.

Comment: Ok, Thank you.  I'll install it now.